# New line in php version 5.6.8 isn't working?

Tags: php

How do we enforce a new line in php. I am using PHP 5.6.8. Trying to create a new line in php which is to use "\n" in double quotes, but this is not working. I have tried in IE, Chrome and Firefox and all of them do not display the new line. For example the code below

```
echo "my name is \n amrak ijrod";
```

should output

```
    my name is
    amrak ijrod
```

But the output that I get is, and without a new line.

```
my name is amrak ijrod
```

`\t` and `\r` works fine though. I tried using multi-line sequence (heredoc) <<< operator.

```
 <?php
    $author = "Scott Adams";
    echo<<<_END
     Normal people believe that if it ain't broke, don't fix it.
     Engineers believe that if it ain't broke, it doesn't have enough
     features yet.
    - $author.
    _END;
    echo "$author";
?>
```

The above code is from the book I am referring to. It should display the text the with the new line but this code also displays all the text in one single line. Is there some settings that I should change in PHP or my way of handling new line is incorrect.

Comment: if that is your actual code, your heredoc syntax is incorrect. get rid of the spaces before your closing identifier. read the manual https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Browsers don't render newlines `\n`. You need to see the page source for that.

Comment: Are you aware of the needing of [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.nl2br.php) function to convert `\n` to `<br>` tags, so they can be interpreted by the browsers?

Comment: ^ exactly. that and `\n` will only render in a new line, if writing to a file.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the space has been reflected here when formatting the code while posting over here, in actual there is no space in the heredoc syntax

Comment: @karma ok, but read the comments again. That's why I said "if" ;-)

Comment: something is a bit unclear though... you wrote *But the output that I get is

my name is amrak ijrod \\without a new line.* - visually speaking, `\\without a new line.` the way you have it in your question, is a bit misleading. Edit: I made an edit.

Comment: To add `\n` does not convert to new line in most languages (except when it comes to writing a file or input.) Otherwise you use `\r` which is return (as if enter was pressed,) and `\t` gives you a tab that otherwise you couldn't do with plaintext.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the browsers render your newlines you should use the HTML tag `<br>` instead of the newline character (`\n`).

To convert the `\n` char to `<br>` tags you can use the [nl2br function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

Obs.: the newline character `\n` works fine when writing file contents using functions like [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Comment: Thanks @Dinei A. Rockenbach that was the info that I did not have. Had no Idea about nl2br function.

Comment: it should also be noted that `\n` will appear as a new line when writing to a file.

Comment: You are right @Fred-ii-, added it to the answer for the sake of clarifying.

Comment: I made an edit for the links URL's. Please use English-based links when referencing ;-)

Comment: Yes, thanks by the editting, I didn't realize that I used the localized link.